# Do insertion and selection sorts comparisons and swaps time are equal?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

In my code i counted the insertion sort and selection sort comparisons and swaps time. But i seen they are equal in comparisons and swaps.
But i used the while loop for insertion. And i can use for loop for selection.
Look at the code.

```
    <?php
$a = array(4,1,7,9,3,2,6,8,10,20,14,29,54,27,563,4,563,334,2,7,5,42,24);
$num = sizeof($a);


for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
  echo "$a[$i] | ";
}
echo "<br>";


echo "<br>Selection<br>";

//selection sort
$swap = 0;
$com = 0;
for ($inner=0; $inner < $num-1; $inner++) { 
  $min = $inner;

  for ($i=$inner+1; $i < $num; $i++) { 

    if ($a[$i] < $a[$min]) {
       $min = $i;

    }
     $com++;

  }
  $swap++;
  $past = $a[$inner];
  $a[$inner] = $a[$min];
  $a[$min] = $past;
}


for ($k=0; $k < $num; $k++) { 
  echo "$a[$k] | ";
}

echo "Com : <span style='color:red;'>$com</span> ";
echo "Swap  :<span style='color:red;'> $swap</span> ";



echo "<br>Insertion<br>";


$swap = 0;
$com = 0;

for ($out=1; $out < $num ; $out++) { 
   $temp = $a[$out];

   for ($i=$out; $i > 0; $i--) { 
         if ($a[$i-1] >= $temp) {
          $a[$i] = $a[$i-1];
         }
         $com++;
   }
   $a[$i] = $temp;
   $swap++;
}

for ($k=0; $k < $num; $k++) { 
  echo "$a[$k] | ";
}

echo "Com : <span style='color:red;'>$com</span> ";
echo "Swap  :<span style='color:red;'> $swap</span> ";




?>
```

Now. How can you tell me insertion sort are faster than selection sort in any sitiuation?? because they are alltime will be euqal in my code!. Thanks

Comment: Did my answer solved your doubts?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I don't have a framework to test the performance of the two algorithms... but I think we can make a performance breakdown on a pure theoretical point of view.

**SELECTION SORT**

It consists in repetitively selecting the first element from the unsorted array and comparing it with the remaining unsorted elements. It is similar to the *bubble sort*, but instead of swapping smaller elements, it keeps the smallest element index updated and swaps it at the end of each iteration.

**INSERTION SORT**

It creates a sorted sub-array and repetitively inserts new elements into it. It follows the logic below:

- Take the first element as a sorted sub-array.
- Insert the second element into the sorted sub-array (shifting as needed).
- Insert the third element into the sorted sub-array (shifting as needed).
- Rinse and repeat until there are no more elements left.

**CONCLUSION**

In terms of time complexity, the **selection sort** is always `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` (which translates into `~O(n^2)`). The **insertion sort**, on the opposite side, may offer a better performance since only its worst case time complexity is `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` (the same as **selection sort**). If I were given the choice, I would chose the **insertion sort** algorithm since the worst thing that can happen is to obtain the same performance of **selection sort**. You can always use `microtime` and perform a quick benchmark on both in order to see which one brings you the best results.